# win7 computer lockup - how to find the cause?

Tags: windows-7, freeze, hardware-failure

So, when i play Sims 3 or League of Legends my PC sometimes gives me **black screen and stops responding** until i reboot it. For *Sims 3* it usually occurs *once in a few hours*, not every session (been fine for the last couple of months, tho I don’t play it that much). For *LoL* – pretty much every session, *once per hour* or so. 
And i am not sure if these problems r the same, but sometimes when i do other random tasks, **PC freezes up for a few seconds** then goes back to normal again. I have no idea whats goin on, and, tbh, im freakin out. Got a few opinions that it might be a faulty hardware, but i have no clue how to find out which one

**This is what i tried so far (and it didnt really help):**

- Official Windows hotfix p95v2810.win64
  (Issue there is described as: This issue occurs because of heavy group policy use and the presence of SCOM causing a deadlock condition between the Lsass.exe process, the Redirected Drive Buffering Subsystem (Rdbss.sys) driver, and the Winsock kernel)
- Jumping between different GPU drivers
- Various benchmark/stress tests such as *Heaven* (did just fine for a couple hours, then i turned it off) and *Prime95* (2 hours, also fine, tho one temperature score* was 90+, so i didnt think its a good idea to let it run further when im not around). Have a HWiNFO-log for the latter. *Memtest64* also found no errors.
- Tweaking Radeon Graphic settings for both games
- Checking power supply voltage in the BIOS, seems okay
- Re-installing Windows with/without updates
- Checking for malware, *CureIt* didnt find anything, there r also no suspicious processes in task manager

*As for cooling/temperature: aside from one mysterious extra-high sensor (marked as Temp2 in SpeedFan and Auxiliary in HWiNFO), others hardly exceed 50-60 even under a heavy load, so i am pretty sure thats not the issue

I do not have a bucket of hardware pieces just lying around, so I would really like a way to figure the issue out without swapping them. Thanks in advance

**System**:

- GPU AMD R9 380
- Win7 64 bit
- Monitor Dell 22" P2217 (2217-4565)
- Motherboard MSI 970A-G43
- CPU AMD FX-Series FX-8350 OEM
- Power supply 700W Zalman ZM700-LX RAM 8GB

EDIT: No hints in game-logs either

Comment: If you didn't check them already, log files should be in `/User/Documents` for both games. Maybe they can give you more information about what caused the crash.

Comment: nothing in LoL folder, only minor script-errors in Sims, tho they didnt cause a crash

Comment: just crashed yet again, could somebody please help me?